# Flutter on Ubuntu - font sizes are tiny

Tags: flutter, ubuntu

Any time I display text in a TextField on flutter desktop for ubuntu the font is tiny.

As you can see in this screen shot, the label 'Name' is 12 points and the text in the text field is also 12 points:

[image]

The text in the text field is about 1/3 the size it should be.

I have a monitor running a 3840 x 2160 under X11 - ubuntu

If I open the Widget detail tree it shows that:
fontSize: 12.0
height: 1.3x
textScalFactor: 1.3

Is this a bug on Flutter/Ubuntu or am I doing something wrong?

Edit:
I've just done a test under wayland and I got the same result - tiny font.

Edit2:
I upgraded to flutter 3.13.7 and still have tiny fonts.

```
Flutter doctor
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.13.3, on Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS 6.2.0-34-generic, locale en_AU.UTF-8)
[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 34.0.0)
    ✗ cmdline-tools component is missing
      Run `path/to/sdkmanager --install "cmdline-tools;latest"`
      See https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line for more details.
    ✗ Android license status unknown.
      Run `flutter doctor --android-licenses` to accept the SDK licenses.
      See https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/linux#android-setup for more details.
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Linux toolchain - develop for Linux desktop
[!] Android Studio (version unknown)
    ✗ Unable to determine Android Studio version.
[✓] VS Code (version unknown)
    ✗ Unable to determine VS Code version.
[✓] Connected device (2 available)
[✓] Network resources

! Doctor found issues in 2 categories.
```

Comment: please show your code thanks. Also did you test it on other platforms?

Comment: So I just created the standard demo app, dropped in a couple of textfields and it doesn't exhibit the problem. The code base I'm running is fairly large so a little hard to extract a working example. Is there anything I should look for that could cause the issue?

Comment: If a standard demo doesn't exhibit the problem then there is no way i can troubleshoot without seeing your code. I would be looking for Textfield style parameters, Expanded widgets, maxlines, many things could be causing the issue